# Contour Plot using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a graph like in this image:

[image: Example Image]

I am trying using a table with 3 columns. I know it is possible do that using programs like "origin" for example. I have done things like that, but Pythong colours seams to be better.

I don't know what is the problem, but I am guessing I am not importing the file in a right way. (the table is a .txt file)[image: Table example]

Can anyone help?

Table example (the real table has more than 10000 lines):

Comment: Are you using any external libraries such as matplotlib?

Comment: Please [edit] the question with the code you have so far, as well as an example of your table.

Comment: I am using matplotlib, And what I am trying to do (I think) is something like that example http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hexbin_demo2.html but I can add my data to any example there, I have tried several different things, but nothing seams to work.
I've added an example of my table, hope you can help
Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have a table of x, y, z data. You can use `pcolor` to display the data, after you have massaged it into the separate components wanted by that function.

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

Nx = 3
Ny = 3

# This is just creating some sample data
xx, yy = meshgrid(range(Nx), range(Ny))
zz = xx + yy
data = vstack([c.flatten() for c in [xx, yy, zz]]).T

# This is reversing the above operation to get x y and z suitable for pcolor
x, y, z = [data[:, i].reshape(Nx, Ny) for i in range(3)]

# Now you can plot
pcolor(x, y, z)
colorbar()
```

Comment: I am trying to do something like that below, because I have a txt file, how can I import it to your model, it seams to work very well by the way thank you.
`import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate

dados=np.loadtxt(r'file.txt')

x =  [dados[:,0]]
y =  [dados[:,1]]
n =  [dados[:,2]]

x = np.asarray(x)
y = np.asarray(y)
z = np.asarray(n)
print "x = ", x
print "y = ", y
print "z = ", z

   
fig=plt.figure()

CF = contour(x,y,z,
         colors = 'k'         
        )
plt.show()
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")        
plt.colorbar()`

Comment: You would just have `data = np.loadtxt(r'file.txt')` and then you would have to determine `Nx` and `Ny` from knowing how the data was sampled. Your call to `contour` will fail as it expects a two-dimensional `z`. Consider adding the code in this comment to the original question - it will allow you to format it properly.